# View is not autoresizing to meet constraints

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I have a hard time wrapping my head around this problem. I have included a simple example where I set constraints to be wrapping the device. However, the view frame is not resizing based on different devices.

Iphone XR -> See how frame is different than holderView

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZTO.jpg

Iphone 8 -> Frame is same size as holderView

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN8XE.jpg

Ideally the holder height and width should change with different devices, however, that is not happening.

Comment: Both images are showing iPhone 8.

Comment: That is under view as, the actual app is being run on simulator. I guess I will include the simulator in the screenshots. You can also see that the frame heights vary from holder heights between images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout seems to look fine.
If they *look* fine in the simulator, they *are* fine.

I suspect that you are printing your frames before the layout gets properly set.
Try moving the debugging print statements to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear`, from `viewDidLoad`.
Also, if you want to wrap the entire device, you need to set constraints around the `superView`, not `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

Although I've done it programmatically, the following is basically the layout you have:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var holderView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    holderView = UIView()
    holderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(holderView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      holderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
      holderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
      holderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
      holderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    ])
    holderView.backgroundColor = .orange

    print(holderView.frame)
    print(view.frame)
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print(holderView.frame)
    print(view.frame)
  }
}
```

In iPhone XR,

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 896.0)
(0.0, 44.0, 414.0, 818.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 896.0)
```

is printed. You can see that `holderView`'s frame is `(0,0,0,0)`. But it gets eventually set. Since you used a storyboard, I think the initial frame size is set to the canvas frame size.

Comment: Hmmm I see, yeah after moving that to viewDidAppear, I see the correct values. Thanks